# is it possible to sync output of multiple running processes or delay output of process?

Tags: process, multiprocessing, stdout

I have several processes running at the same time,
in each process there is one c program,
when these processes are running, each process/programs output some log information to stdout from time to time.
since they may run at the same time, the log information may be overlapped with others.
Is it possible to sync the output of multiple processes so that in the stdout, logging information from the same process is put together.

My idea is to delay the output to stdout. A process output its all logging information to stdout only when it finishes/exits. But I'm not familiar with stdout and flush in C, how to do it?

can any give some suggestions? thanks!

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're entering the fraught and complex world of [Inter-process communication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication).

I'd recommend a few simpler approaches:  Write a logger service that performs a `select` on all of the output channels of the running processes in a single-threaded manner, and then writes to your output log in a sequential and sensible manner.  There might even be services already out there that do this.

Alternatively, just write different log files (to files, not `stdout`) for each process!  This will ensure that your logging data is not interleaved in unpredictable ways.

Or protect your logging routine with some kind of mutex or semaphore built on top of whichever OS-level IPC primitives you have available to you.

Comment: that is a bit complex, how about stdout and flush? but it seems in C there is no flush

Comment: Writing to multiple different files is too complex?  That would be how I would solve this problem.  Output to `stdout` is not buffered in the way you expect, I think.  `flush` doesn't make a lot of sense in this context for solving your problem, although analogous low-level terminal control routines do exist, they aren't what you want.

Comment: actually I'm doing a series of tests. Although simultaneously there may be several processes. Altogether there are many processes, that will lead to many output files.